# Can I clear two seperate ranges with a button script? Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to clear two seperate ranges with the click of a button but can't figure out how to combine the ranges together

I use this for one range and the other range I need to combine is 'E15:J18'

function ClearCells() {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('OOTW');

sheet.getRange('E7:J12').clearContent();}`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to clear multiple, discontinuous ranges on a Spreadsheet with a single function.

My suggestion would be to add another line to your function that gets the subsequent discontinuous range, and clears it.

```
function clearCells() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("OOTW");
  sheet.getRange("E7:J12").clearContent();
  sheet.getRange("E15:J18").clearContent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Clear RangeList

```
function clearRangeList() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRangeList(["E7:J12","E15:J18"]).getRanges().forEach(rg => rg.clearContent())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to use `clearContent()` to multiple ranges of `'E7:J12', 'E15:J18'` of "OOTW" sheet.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
SpreadsheetApp
  .getActive()
  .getSheetByName('OOTW')
  .getRangeList(['E7:J12', 'E15:J18'])
  .clearContent();
```

#### References:

- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRangeList(String))
- [clearContent() of Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#clearContent())